# Preciso cadastrar vários produtos

Tags: c++

Estou criando um código de cadastro de Produto, porém só consigo armazenar um único produto. Como melhorar o código?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void novoProduto(){
    string nome="Patrick Oliveira de Souza";
    float custo, venda;

    system("cls");
    cout<<"\tCadastro de Produto\n\n\n";
    cout<<"\nNome do Produto: ";
    cin>>nome;
    cout<<"\nPreco de Custo: ";
    cin>>custo;
    cout<<"\nPreco de Venda: ";
    cin>>venda;
}

int main()
{
    int op;
    cout<<"\tCadastro de Produto\n\n\n";
    cout<<"\n<1>Novo Produto";
    cout<<"\n<2>Listar Produtos";
    cout<<"\n\tOpcao: ";
    cin>>op;

    switch (op){
        case 1:
            novoProduto();
            break;

        /*case 2:
            break*/


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la agora? Veja o [tour] para entender como funciona. Ajudaria muito indicar para todo mundo que a solução foi útil e satisfatória para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma bem básica de adicionar esta funcionalidade:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Produto { //esta é uma forma bem simplificada
    public:
        string Nome;
        float Custo; //em código real não pode usar float para valor monetário
        float Venda;
};
    
void novoProduto(vector<Produto> produtos) { //esta é uma forma bem ingênua de fazer isto
    produtos.push_back(Produto());
    cout << "\tNovo Produto\n";
    cout << "\nNome do Produto: ";
    cin >> produtos[produtos.size() - 1].Nome;
    cout << "\nPreco de Custo: ";
    cin >> produtos[produtos.size() - 1].Custo;
    cout << "\nPreco de Venda: ";
    cin >> produtos[produtos.size() - 1].Venda;
}

int main() {
    vector<Produto> produtos;
    int op;
    do {
        cout << "\n\tCadastro de Produto\n";
        cout << "\n<1> Novo Produto";
        cout << "\n<2> Listar Produtos";
        cout << "\n\tOpcao: ";
        cin >> op;
        system("cls");
        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                novoProduto(produtos);
                break;
        }
    } while (op != 0);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NlS5OR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/knojebhh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Products.cpp).

Note que houve duas alterações principais. Criei um vetor para armazenar os vários produtos e criei uma classe para agrupar os dados de um produto. Fiz uma série de mudanças cosméticas e adicionei um laço para permitir várias ações na mesma execução.

Fiz várias simplificações, em código real muita coisa deveria ser feita de forma diferente.

Comment: quando vou cadastrar um produto e coloco o nome do produto com espaço ele não funciona. por ex.: celular teste.    Outra coisa é valor de venda e custo se eu colocar 1,50. O programa não aceita mesmo mudando a variável para double.

Comment: Este já é outro problema. O `cin` não é adequado para textos em geral. Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/42338/101